# Transistor biasing arrangement

Tags: power-supply, transistors, power, motor, linear

I am trying to learn about transistor biasing, and can’t seem to wrap my head around it.

First of all I’ll explain what I’m trying to accomplish. I’m trying to build a linear 0-100 V power supply which will be capable of supplying loads with a varying impedance. I would like to be able to control the voltage to a motor or soldering iron which usually have quite a low impedance. I also intend to use this power supply for anodizing titanium, which has a relatively high impedance (~3-5 kΩ).

Ideally I would like to be able to control the power supply with a potentiometer, but I’ve blown up almost every single one I have now.

[image]

I’ve attached a photo of the circuit I currently have. Along with it you can see the spice analysis and transistor arrangement with a 0.7 Ω resistor as the load. The test is a DC sweep at V1 from 0-100 V with the potentiometer fully open.

While testing my circuit I found that the transistors aren’t fully saturated which would be why I’ve damaged so many. Also I do know that using a motor with this low an impedance would use a huge amount of current and requires multiple transistors in parallel to provide it.

Could someone please help me to understand how to correctly bias a transistor with a varying load impedance?

Comment: That's not how you design a power supply. Where's the feedback? Why is Q3 upside-down? A linear supply for a low-impedance load is usually not a good idea.

Comment: This is the first circuit I’ve tried to design and I didn’t go to school for this so I’m working from the basic knowledge I’ve found on Google. Originally I was trying to use a single npn configuration which the potentiometer didn’t have the current available to power the motor especially with the low gain since it wasn’t fully saturated. At least that’s what I’ve come to understand so far.

Comment: Also from what I understand this could be considered a negative feedback common collector. Instead of the load being placed on the collector it is placed on the emmitter. Ref. - https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/semiconductors/chpt-4/feedback/

Comment: So I think the biggest issue I’m having is trying to build this with varying impedance. Currently the configuration I have “works” just not very well. But high a high impedance load in place of the 0.7 ohm resistor it greatly reduces the voltage and that would be why it doesn’t work. If I were to place a load resistor in parallel with the load. Would this fix the issue with the high impedance load not conducting enough to turn the transistors on?

Comment: The emitter resistor doesn't really function as feedback in a circuit like this. What you need is something to sense the output voltage and compare it to some kind of stable voltage reference (a TL431 is a good choice for that); your conventional linear regulator circuit consists of an op amp driving a current gain stage, with feedback as described above.

Comment: I also fixed q3 in ltspice I didn’t realize it was upside down. I do have it wired correctly with q3 reversed.

Comment: @Hearth yeah I’ve looked at some of the voltage regulators online and I’ve used the lm317. I don’t have access to a tl783. But I do have a lot of transistors around. What I wanted to do originally was a tl783 with current boosting transistors. If I changed the load resistor to 100 ohms, and ran the output parallel to the load resistor, that does fix the high impedance issue. But it reduces vbe across q1 and q2. What would be the best way to push q1 and q2 into saturation?

Comment: "the potentiometer fully open" is not a useful description - what do you mean by that? *Open* circuit - no current flowing? *Open* door - lots of current flowing? Something else?

Comment: `I’ve blown up [all my potentiometers]` A (non-"power") pot is about 0.2 W max. To survive 111 V, the pot needs to be 100 kΩ at least. In consequence, load to it should be very low indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fun arrangement is slightly different:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fb0HTs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This definitely seems like it will work from what I can see using circuit lab. It also works for both high and low impedance loads. 

The vbe for a low impedance load is ~0.6 volts and ~1.4v on q1 and q3 and 0.6v and 0.6v for a high impedance load. Is there any way to raise the vbe to switch the transistor fully on?

Comment: @Infernoman: I'm afraid I don't get what you're after: Which transistor/\$V_{BE}\$ are you asking about? I picture the transistors used in continuous rather than in switch mode.

Comment: I could be misunderstanding how the circuit works as well. So forgive me for my ignorance but the vbe is the base voltage minus emitter voltage correct? And to switch the transistor fully on to minimize heat losses you need a voltage of +5v for an npn transistor. But both q1 and q3 range from 0.6-1.4v

Comment: The overall circuit is a potentiometer dividing the supply voltage, followed by an *emitter follower* "sourcing" a load: the goal is not to keep transistor losses low - no way to reduce losses with "linear" circuitry -, but to have the output voltage close to the input voltage. There is no way to (forward)bias an [Si-BJT's](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_junction_transistor#Function) BE diode to 5 V without destroying it - you may be mixing this up with (enhancement-mode) [(MOS)FET](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSFET#Modes_of_operation)s.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that for me. At least I’m slowly starting to understand things. While doing some searching I found a feedback based motor controller for universal motors which is very similar. - https://www.nutsvolts.com/magazine/article/scr_principles_and_circuits figure 16 is the one I’m talking about. With a bridge rectifier and 2 transistors configured as an scr. Would this cover all of my bases?

Comment: Investigate the basics of linear power supplies - if nothing else, it helps you fix what you think to need. There is *one* place for SCRs in contemporary power supplies: as a crowbar device. Note that the configuration of the transistors is fundamentally different: in a "pseudo-SCR", each collector is connected to the base of the complementary transistor, while in a [(complementary) Darlington](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sziklai_pair) there is one "input" transistor the base of which is used and an "output" one with collector and emitter used to interface with the rest of the world/circuit.